# How to connect to Lotus notes datadase from OS X

Tags: macos, lotus-notes

Is it possible to connect to lotus notes database from mac? I have LN installed on my computer and LN itself can connect to any LN database but I have no idea how it is done, if it if via jdbc connection (i couldn't find any notesSQL jdbc driver for that) or some way else.

I know that it is very easy on windows - via the win32ole object. But how it is possible on mac?

any help much appreciated.

any ruby/python/java code that runs on mac will help. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Lotus Notes has it's own propitiatory Java API for accessing resources (not JDBC). The core of this is bundled with the Lotus Notes client in the Notes.jar (this can normally be found in the notes install location)

From previous experience you will need to make sure you run any application you write with the same JVM that is used to run Lotus Notes (Notes is just a Eclipse application these days) to ensure all the correct native libraries are also picked up. You will also need access to your Lotus Notes ID file in order to authenticate you with the Domino server that hosts the database. If Notes is running then you will normally be authenticated as the current user.

A good (but old) introduction to writing applications using this API can be found here:

https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/06082009125716amweb7tu.htm

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Java_access_pt1/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately, I have no experience in writing application API or wraping API code into an application.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about an equivalent to using the Lotus Notes OLE classes (NotesUIWorkspace, NotesUIDatabase, etc.) to drive the Notes client UI to navigate and display data in the Notes client's window, the answer is no - there is no equivalent technology on OS/X.

Apart from that, there are several APIs available to access Notes and Domino data. I briefly mention a few of them in this [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791910/api-to-integrate-with-domino/30794895#30794895).