# What are the software need be installed to connect ibm lotus and domino notes using Java?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse, ibm-domino

I am totally new to IBM lotus and domino notes. I just want to know how to connect IBM domino using java and what are the software I should have installed in my machine.

I gone through many websites but I didn't get any proper tutorial websites. currently I am referring to this [page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_EXAMPLES_SERVERNAME_PROPERTY_SESSION_JAVA.html).

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? There are multiple ways... You could use DIIOP, notes.jar, Webservices, just to mention a few.. As asked this question is way to broad.

Answer (score 2):

See my [answer to a previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791910/api-to-integrate-with-domino/30794895#30794895). That answer is broader than just talking about how to connect to Notes and Domino from Java, but it does include a good summary of the options you have from Java, and there's a reference to a very old book that you can download for free and is useful even if it is old. It has an excellent introduction to the principles of Notes and Domino in addition to a lot of information about the Java API. Once you've read it, you should be able to ask more specific questions and we will be able to help you with them.

As far as software goes, you may not need to install anything besides Domino Designer, but the truth is it depends on what environment you are going to develop in, what environment you are going to run in, and what choice you make about the different ways you can access Notes/Domino data from Java.