# How to write to NSF from outside HCL Notes?

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I have written some test scripts in Java which uses Selenium and I would like to write results in an Note NSF file, e.g. OpenLog.nsf

I wonder how I can do this within my test program which is running from my local machine which has the Notes client installed?

How do I include references to the notes.jar and user ID in my java programme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [my answer to this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791910/api-to-integrate-with-domino/30794895#30794895) here on StackOverflow. Pay attention to point 2 and follow the links to chapters that Bob Balaban posted from his book about programming for Notes and Domino in Java. It's very old material but all the introductory information about how to access the classes in Notes.jar and use them from your program is still valid.

At a minimum, this will give you enough knowledge of the class and method names so that you can use your favorite search engine to find more details, or to come back here to StackOverflow after trying it yourself so you can ask more specific questions about how to solve any problems that you encounter.